# Print formatted output JAXB object

Tags: java, jaxb

I have this JAB object that I want to print as readable string when I populate it:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment_response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymentResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
    public String transactionType;
    ....
}
```

I tried to implement this:

```
      PaymentResponse response = new PaymentResponse("error", 340, "Please check input data for errors!", "has already been used!");

      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PaymentResponse.class);

      Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

      jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

      StringWriter responsesw = new StringWriter();
      jaxbMarshaller.marshal(response, responsesw);

      System.out.println(response.toString())
```

But I get only this `org.rest.models.PaymentResponse@71b6bc42`
How I can get the extra XML into readable text?

Comment: Can you provide the complete PaymentResponse  class ?

Comment: Do not write on console `toString` result - `System.out.println(response.toString())` but `System.out.println(responsesw.toString())`.

Comment: Thanks. this was the issue